# How to expose kubernetes web server to port 80

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ip

I have a tornado webserver + nginx + DNS. I have moved the webserver to a kubernetes pod and same with nginx.

But i realized that cant expose to port 80 then i kept nginx outside from kubernetes and changed webserver ip by the ip of the pod and works without problems.

The problem is that each time the ssh server restarts the pod's ip changes and i need to manually change the ip on nginx conf.

How can i or keep pod's ip between reloads or expose nginx on a pod to outside?

Answer (score 1):

Use a load balancer between DNS and nginx ingress controller. The load balancer can accept traffic on port 80 and forward to nodeport on which nginx ingress controller is exposed.

Alternatively use the [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and run it with `hostNetwork: true` in deployment pod spec to run nginx ingress controller directly on port `80` in host's network namespace. Then configure DNS to forward traffic to `nodeip:80`

Create a cluster IP type kubernetes service and an [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to access pod exposed via nginx. Nginx ingress controller will forward traffic to POD IPs directly. There is no change needed anywhere in this setup in case pod IP changes because nginx ingress controller watches for any change in POD IP and updates the `nginx.conf` accordingly.

Comment: I mean that the pod is accessible through port 80 on host like `curl pod_ip:80`. But when i try to do it using NodePort service it gives me error because im trying to use a low port

Comment: you can not use 80 for a nodeport

Comment: That is exactly my question, how to workaround this

Comment: why do you need 80 as nodeport ?

Comment: For expose it to the outside through a DNS. Having for example www.mydomain.com access directly to the nginx pod

Comment: So you don't have or want a load balancer between DNS and nginx? A load balancer can accept the traffic on port 80 and forward to nodeport. Other option is to run the nginx with hostNetwork: true on port 80 and configure DNS to NODEIP:80

Comment: I dont have a load balancer, and if this helps me to solve the problem i dont have any problem to use it, i will try it. The second option if i understood correctly is run nginx outside kubernetes and forward the requests to the kubernetes pod, correct? this is what i have right now but each time i restart the pod i get a different ip, if i could set an static local ip this would solve my problem too.

Comment: To avoid IP issue you can use nginx ingress controller. Check updated answer

Comment: I have installed already ingress-nginx, and set my backend pod to hostNetwork true. But when i try to apply my ingress i get `Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post https://pmplab-nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.default.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s: context deadline exceeded`. I have seen this error multiples times on internet but anything that could help me